# Is there a simple algorithm to detect starter and ender characters of each scope?

Tags: python, string, parsing

The picture graph explanation below looks kinda complex, but it is very simple. I need an algorithm for my experimental project about analyzing python code as an usual **string**.

[image: graphic explanation]

I want to detect all the starter and ender character of each scope and output them in an array as the picture shows. Some of them must be copied as exactly same several times, because it must show that it is the ender character for more than one starter, just like a normal curly brace languages whould appear like this: `{hi{hello{my friend}}}`

Is there a simple algorithm for that? thanks.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Yeah, I uploaded an image, "graphic explanation", you can click on it, and see )))

Comment: @leodevbro, martineau was pointing out that is better to post code (as text) rather the images. You can post both code (what you tried) and then the image explanation

Comment: This isn't really the kind of image of code we have problems with, though. This isn't code we need to debug, or something we have any reason to run - it's a *diagram* explaining the goal of the question, which is to *analyze* code in a particular way. I say this image is fine.

Comment: The input and output could be posted as text (and there's an argument to be made that they should be, along with the image), but there's other stuff in the image that can't be posted as plain text.

Comment: How do you want to handle comments? Should they be ignored, or should the last character of a comment sometimes be counted as the last character of a scope? (Comments don't follow the indentation rules, so you'll have problems defining your desired output if you want to treat comments as significant.)

Comment: Thanks for the question. I would like the algorithm to be very Python aware, I mean it must know what is just a comment, and what is functional code. But it is also fine if the algorithm will be very naive and primitive - with just aware of indentaion, it will be fine because this is just an experimental demo for simple analysis. I think, such algo already exist, otherwise, how a computer runs Python code? It detects the scope starter/ender indexes/locations, Am I right?

Comment: You should make an attempt to define what you mean by "scope". The usual meaning has to do with visibility of identifiers; by that definition, none of the blocks you show is a scope. (That is, `i`, `j` and `k` are global variables; their scope is the entire file.) On the other hand, there are scopes not correlated with indentation (and therefore not terminated with a newline character); these include lambdas and comprehensions. (And you can write loops on a single line if the loop body is simple enough.)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for the [`tokenize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html) module, which processes a string into a sequence of Python tokens. The start and end of an indented block are reported as INDENT and DEDENT tokens, and you're looking for the last character of the first preceding token that contains non-whitespace text.

`tokenize` is smart enough to recognize that there are no indented blocks (as Python defines them) in the following examples:

```
'''
This is a multi-line string literal,
    so indentation inside it isn't syntactically significant.
'''

# This is implicit line continuation, despite the presence of a colon.
function = (lambda x:
    x**2 + 2*x - 1)
```

However, it is only a tokenizer, not a parser. It can't recognize invalid syntax unless that syntax is something like `?`, which is not a valid token.

`tokenize` reports source locations as `(row, column)` tuples, with rows starting at 1 and columns starting at 0 (which is kind of weird), but you can process that back into a string index if you want.